# Toolbar not showing up?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, toolbar

I am trying to implement a toolbar in my activity but it doesn't seem to work. My MainActivity is a ViewPager, which contains Fragments 1 and 2. I tried to implement my toolbar directly into the Viewpager, this didn't work so instead I tried to wrap my Viewpager in a RelativeLayout and include the toolbar in that RelativeLayout, but this also doesn't work.

The layout for my toolbar (app_bar.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/app_bar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/CustomToolBarStyle"
android:title="Something"
android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

this is how I've implemented the toolbar in my activity (activity_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/app_bar"/>   <-----------

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is what I've done in my activity's Java file to set the toolbar as the actionbar (MainActivity.java):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager pager;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FloatingActionButton fab;
Toolbar tb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_main);
    tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    pager.setAdapter(new myAdapter(fragmentManager));

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    //.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_HASH")
    //.build();

    //do not make visible while testing!!
    //mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);             <------------------
```

it would really appreciate it if someone is able to help me out. Have a nice day!

Vidal

Comment: Have you tried [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView)? Says you should set the size manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `id` from include tag and add `android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"` to your `ViewPager`.

Comment: Thanks! got it working, somehow. The statusbar (which contains battery percentage, wifi status, etc) is somehow overlapping the toolbar but i guess I'll find out how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Change your toolbar height from `wrap_content` to you `?attr/actionBarSize` as shown below:

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/CustomToolBarStyle"
    android:title="Something"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and position your viewpager below `Toolbar` as shown below

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/pager"
         android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="#FFFFFF" />

     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
         android:id="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Got it working but there's a weird bug causing some sort of toolbar being present in the first Fragment only and the actionbar as a whole is way too small

Comment: If action bar is size is too small, then you can always set the width and height of your liking. Just set the desired height and width in dp.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions :)